# I can't read original DICOM file name as sent by a Remote AE to C-STORE SCP using fo-dicom

Tags: c#, fo-dicom

I have C-STORE SCP app (modified from the example provided by fo-dicom contributors) that can receive and save the DICOM file sent from remote AE. The original C-STORE SCP app saves DICOM file with a different name derived from tag value, that's ok for my case. Additionally, from within the SCP app, I want to read the original dicom file name as sent by the remote AE. Let's say, remote AE sent dicom file named "mydicom.dcm" to C-STORE SCP, I want to read that file name ("mydicom.dcm" in this case). How can I do this in fo-dicom?

I tried the following without any success.

```
public async Task<DicomCStoreResponse> OnCStoreRequestAsync(DicomCStoreRequest request)
{
    ...

    DicomFile sDcmFileName = request.File;

    ...
}
```

BTW, I am a newbie in DICOM and fo-dicom. Any hint or reference will suffice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The DICOM file name only is relevant in the context of DICOM Media, like e.g. images stored on a CD, DVD, etc. Besides that, DICOM files will typically also be stored on drives of systems that are not officially DICOM media.

The content of a DICOM file consists of 2 main parts: the File Meta Information and the data set. It is the data set that contains the actual medical information and only this part will be send over the network in a DICOM Association from a Storage SCU to a Storage SCP, using C-STORE-RQ messages.

To give you a two sentence answer: the original DICOM file name is not send over by the Storage SCU to the Storage SCP. When the Storage SCP wants to encapsulate the received data set and store it in a local DICOM file, it will always need to create a new file name.